# ARKit Drawing 3D paper plane with rounded corner

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw 3D paper plane with rounded corner in ARKit, but I can't do that.

I did that with bazier path:

```
    // create bezeir path
    let path  = UIBezierPath()
   
    // A bezier path
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.025))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.02, y: -0.005))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -0.02, y: -0.005))
    path.close()
     
    // create arrow shape
    let arrowShape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.001)
    arrowShape.chamferRadius = 50
  
    // create new node
    arrownode = SCNNode(geometry: arrowShape);
       
    // set arrow color
    arrownode!.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
```

The result :

[image]

I need like this exactly but with rounded corner.

Answer (score 1):

An instance property `chamferRadius` creates chamfer for extruded zDepth, not for XY path.

```
let arrowShape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.005)
arrowShape.chamferRadius = 20
```

[image]

If you want to create a rounded corners use the following method for path:

```
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint)
```

or

```
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint, controlPoint1: CGPoint, controlPoint2: CGPoint)
```